# Spring Security login issue -

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm rather new to Spring/Spring Security, I've already tried my best solving this issue, but I just don't seem to get it right over and over again. The issue is following: login does not work properly - even with right credentials it keeps telling that they appear to be incorrect. 
I'm using Spring Security and Spring mvc + Oracle (hibernate + jpa). I would really appreciate any help, thank you very much in advance!

Here are my configuration files. (parts)

```
1. security.xml

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<!-- <password-encoder hash="md5" /> -->

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="
          SELECT username, password, 'TRUE'
          FROM users WHERE username=?"

            authorities-by-username-query="
          SELECT u.username, ur.authority FROM users u, user_roles ur 
          WHERE u.user_id = ur.user_id AND u.username=?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

2. web.xml

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

3. data.xml

<!-- Transaction managing using the @Transactional annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>msgs</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

<!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// "-->

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

</bean>

<!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory configuration -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tsystems.javaschool.kts.domain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you also post your login jsp page?
And do you see the select user query in your logging?

Comment: Sure, here http://pastebin.com/mhAx7XcE

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this? If you list that you can save us from suggesting things you've already tried.

Comment: Sorry, how exactly should it appear in the log?

Comment: Tried reorganizing database, modifying queries in authetication provider, changing data source. Also, if that is relevant, I have a warning in security.xml, stating that bean named dataSource not found.

Comment: Yup, that'd be the problem (datSource not found)

Comment: Well, i reorganized project a bit, now that this warning is gone, login is still not not working properly. I get following error message trying to login :  PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username, password, 'TRUE' from users where USERNAME=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this table DOES exists. I've tried stating schema explicitly, even switching case in queries, nothing worked. What could the problem possibly be? I'm using oracle xe and c3p0 in dataSource, again, if this is of any relevance.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see error now, but I can get you some example witch works for me:

part of web.xml:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

.......

Did you include XML file (security.xml) in yours web.xml (another part of web.xml)?

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Part of security-config.xml (DATA is shema, ROLE and USER are table):

```
<http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_GUEST, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=t"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp?logout=t"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="ds" authorities-by-username-query="select USERNAME as username, ROLE as authority from DATA.ROLE where USERNAME=?"
            users-by-username-query="select USERNAME as username, PASSWORD as password, 'true' AS enabled from DATA.USER where USERNAME=?"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

And part of JSP page (login.jsp):

```
<c:when test="${param.logout == 't'}">

// show when I logout
.......

</c:when>
<c:when test="${param.login_error == 't'}">

// show when username or password is not correct
.......

</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
.....
<form method="POST" action="<%= response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "/j_spring_security_check") %>" >
......
<input class="input" type="text" name="j_username" />
......
<input class="input" type="password" name="j_password" />
.....
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="Login" />
.....
</c:otherwise>
```

If still won't, please write here.